# Unable to install Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I have successfully installed Ruby using the 'rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p484.exe' but I am unable to install Rails. I get an error 'The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.'
How do I resolve this ?
[image]

Comment: It states in the error message that you should try downloading the devkit. Have you downloaded the devkit?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded DevKit,

Comment: what about the instructions in the DevKit?  Or, If you think you've followed them all, you might want to try restarting your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download Ruby 1.9.3

2) Download DevKit file from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20110712-1620-sfx.exe)

3) Extract DevKit to path C:\Ruby193\DevKit

4) `cd C:\Ruby193\DevKit`

5) `ruby dk.rb init`

6) `ruby dk.rb review`

7) `ruby dk.rb install`

you can verify the rails installation by typing this on command prompt

```
rails -v
```

Comment: How do I verify the rails installation ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. please click on check mark if that answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

If the devkit made changes to the PATH, you will have to restart the cmd terminal.